# There was no channel actively listening

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, iis

maybe you can help me set up my WCF service.

First, here is my config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  <bindings />
<services>
  <service name="AuthenticatorService.Authenticator">
    <endpoint address="auth" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      name="AuthEndpoint" contract="AuthInterface.IAuthenticator" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MetadataEndpoint"
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And this is how I call my service from c#:

```
        //This creates a link to the WCF service using basicHttpBingind
        httpFactory = new ChannelFactory<IAuthenticator>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://myUrl/auth.svc"));

        httpProxy = httpFactory.CreateChannel();
```

It worked fine when I was doing this on localhost but now it keeps telling me no endpoint was found.

Also, the server generated the following error:

System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://myURL/auth.svc/$metadata'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.

Im really confused, I have no idea why this is happening. Do I need to create another service file for the metadata exchange?

Do I need to set a baseAddress?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How did you deploy the service?  I assume the service is running in IIS on your box - did you try hitting the service URL (http://myUrl/auth.svc) in a browser to see if it is indeed up?